# problem with fonts in the new blogger interface

Tags: fonts, blogger

in new blogger interface when you want to post something there is new option (add more fonts)
[image]
So, after I added font I can't remove it there is no option to remove it and also I can't find it in html
So, what can we do to solve this problem?
maybe disable it by add code if we can't remove it or something like that.

the font is lato

[my website url](https://ezzeddinisalm.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Analizing your blog url, the code for that font ( <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?display=swap&amp;family=Lato">) is located just above the closing head tag: </head>. Maybe looking there in the html code and deleting that line? Sorry I can't help more, I didn't try that option yet.

Comment: There is no way right now, you have to send [feedback](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/58098347?hl=en) to Blogger team